Error with pdf-to-img library in TypeScript (NestJS): "esModule() is not a function"
I'm working on a NestJS project using TypeScript and trying to convert a PDF (from either a stream or a buffer) into images. I decided to use the pdf-to-img library. However, when I try to use the library, I encounter the following error:
TypeError: esModule() is not a function

Sample code
async convertPdfToImages(pdfBuffer: Buffer): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const images = await pdfToImg.convert(pdfBuffer); // Conversion
      console.log(images);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

Library used: pdf-to-img
I have tried other libraries too like pdf2pic but it requires the graphics to install on the system.
Is there any alternative to it to convert the pdf to image?
I have pdf readable stream / pdf buffer
Thank you

Are there any other alternatives or reference?
